# Using loops to output boxes

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++

My code for outputting boxes, outputs only spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class box{
int x, y;
public:
box(int i, int j){ x = i; y = j; }

friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, box o);
};


ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, box o)
{
register int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < o.x; i++)
    stream << "*";

stream << "\n";
for (j = 1; j < o.y-1; j++){
    for (i = 0; i < o.x; i++)
        if (i == 0 || i == o.x - 1) stream << "*";
        else stream << " ";
    stream << "\n";
}
for (i = 0; i < o.x; i++)
    stream << "*";
stream << "\n";

return stream;
 }


 int main(){
box a(14, 6), b(30, 7), c(40, 5);
cout << a << b << c;

return 0;
}
```

This is supposed to output some boxes made of `*`
but the only thing it does is create some newlines and spaces.
It doesn't even print  `box b` or `box c`

EDIT : i found the mistake and corrected it , thanks to everyone

Comment: `box(int i, int j){ i = x; j = y; }` You have it reversed. Wouldn't happen with a proper usage of initialization list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that instead of

```
box(int i, int j){ i = x; j = y; }
```

you mean

```
box( int i, int j ) : x( i ), y( j ) {}
```

And it is better to declare the operator like

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const box &o);
```